# Syslog in file doesn't work, interpreter does

Tags: python, syslog

I am trying the following code on a Mac OSX Yosemite machine, running python3.4

```
import syslog
syslog.syslog("This is a test")
```

If i run this directly into the interpreter by launching it independently, lo and behold, there is a line in my /var/log/system.log

However, if I make a new file called `junk` and type that in then run `python3 junk`, there are no errors and nothing appears in my system log.

I have looked everywhere for a solution. I am running as root, so there's definitely not a permissions issue (or at least definitely not a solvable one).

I simply don't know where to even look for some feedback. I even tried setting it so that it prints also to stderr, which shows up in stderr but not in the log file. I tried setting it so that if it fails to access the log, it will use stderr instead, but nothing showed up, so clearly python *thinks* its talking to the log.

Any ideas?

Comment: nothing in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: nothing at all. but it's /var/log/system.log

Comment: what about `sudo grep -rnw '/var/log' -e 'This is a test'`

Comment: God I'm stupid. Thanks Roberto. I didn't realize that the system log was appending a different tag to the log entry when it runs from a file than when it runs from the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why it worked for you on MacOSX directly in Python (it didn't for me). However, after adding the priority, it worked for me in the Python interpreter, and in a separate program. For example:

```
import syslog
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, 'bla')
```

Might be that there's a default priority that `syslog()` uses, which is filtered out in MacOSX so that it doesn't go to the system log.

Comment: Hey thanks, unfortunately that also didn't work for me. I have tried various levels of logging and none appear to make a difference. My guess is that there is something in the shell environment that gets passed to the interpreter in interactive mode, but not when it's parsing a file.... no idea what or how or why though.

Comment: Hmmm odd. What if you specifically initialize using `syslog.openlog()`?

Comment: Turns out that is the solution, basically the interpreter tags the line with 'Python' but when run from a file file it tags it with the name of the file.